# Expected End of Statement While Using "=" on same line as "Dim"

Tags: vba

```
Dim doubles = {1.5, 2, 9.9, 18}
```

This always returns an "Expected End of Statement" error, highlighting the = sign. All the guides I see for VBA declare variables this way at one point or another but it always gives me this error, even if I just copy paste the code.

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of doubles?

Comment: You cannot `Dim` a variable and assign values to it all in one line with VBA like you can with VB.NET

Comment: I'm trying to teach myself how to work with arrays in general, this is just one example of code I entered that didn't, but it always has an issue when I use "=" on the same line as "Dim"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go a bit fancy, and use the `:` syntactic sugar. Thus, it would look like that the array is on the same line as the `Dim`, otherwise it is tough:

```
Sub TestMe()

    'Array starts at 1!
    Dim doubles As Variant: doubles = [{1, 2.54, 9.1, 18}]
    Debug.Print doubles(2)

    'Array starts at 0!
    doubles = Array(1, 2.54, 9, 1, 18)
    Debug.Print doubles(2)

End Sub
```

You can also use the `[{...}]` syntax, to declare the array, thus make everyone around a bit crazy, as the array starts with 1, and not with 0, when it is declared like this.

Comment: Thanks, this was very informative. On a slightly related note, I'm using VBA in access and was wondering how I can view what my array looks like. It doesn't work the same way I'm accustomed to, and I can't figure out how to get my VBA code to actually output anywhere.

Comment: @Roland - select the array in the code and click Shift+F9. This is the best way in VBA. `Ctrl+G` to see the immediate window, where you can see what the arrays members are if you write `Debug.Print doubles(2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign on the same line, and in the same statement, as the Dim and if you want an array of doubles you need

```
Dim doubles() As Variant
doubles = Array(1.5, 2.0, 9.9, 18.0)
```